# Ajuda com Json para pegar valor de API

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando conseguir apenas o retorno de uma variavel dessa api "buy" que seria o valor de compra, porém quando tento ela me retorna a tabela toda, alguém poderia me iluminar?

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://broker.negociecoins.com.br/api/v3/btcbrl/ticker"));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: print_r($data->$buy);

Comment: @LucasBrogni corrigindo, o correto é $data->buy

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize  `print_r($data->buy);`

Comment: Bom dia, não deu certo Lucas, continou sem me retornar nada. se eu tiro o Buy, ele retorna tudo, com o buy, ele me retorna nada, meu código ficou assim.                       

<?php
  
   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.bitcointrade.com.br/v1/public/BTC/ticker"));
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($data->buy);
  echo "</pre>"; ?>

Comment: @EduardoCardosodossantos ali no comentário da pergunta, você tinha dito que tinha funcionado '-'

Comment: funcionou com aquele api da questão, porém testando com outros não funcionou, como esse do exemplo acima, não entendi o motivo, a sintax é a mesma.

Comment: @EduardoCardosodossantos acessei a API agora. Ele não funciona nesta outra por que o retorno dela não é diretamente o buy: 

`{
message: null,
data: {
high: 27200,
low: 25000,
volume: 182.71434794,
trades_quantity: 2538,
last: 25317.7,
sell: 25269.32,
buy: 25253,
date: "2018-08-08T11:36:18.909Z",
},
}`
Existe um data dentro dele. Adicione ->     Nesse caso use `print_r($data -> data -> buy)`